# Regular expression to strip all non numeric characters except scientific notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, math, scientific-notation

I'm looking for a way to clean a number in Javascript, stripping all non-numeric characters unless it would break scientific notation.  For example, I am looking for the following output...

- `123.45` => `123.45`
- `1a23.45` => `123.45`
- `1a23.4re5` => `123.45`
- `*(@#123.45jkd` => `123.45`
- `7.71234e+1` => `7.71234e+1`

I am more than happy to split on the `.` first and deal with the number as 2 different parts, if need be.

Comment: What constitutes "numeric"? Is "NaN" numeric? How about "Infinity"? What about "0xABC123"? Are you only interested in decimal numbers with possible powers of ten using `e` (i.e. "1.23e4")? What about capital `E`?

Answer (score 3):

You can return any string that evaluates to a number,

and clean the ones that don't.

```
function cleanNumber(num){
    var N= Number(num);
    if(parseFloat(num)=== N) return num;
    return num.replace(/\D+/g, '') || '0';
}
```

cleanNumber('7.71234e+1')

> > (String) 7.71234e+1

Or you can convert the strings to numbers and return a number-

```
function cleanNumber2(num){
    var N= Number(num);
    if(parseFloat(num)=== N) return N;
    return Number(num.replace(/\D+/g, '')) || 0;
}
```

cleanNumber2('7.71234e+1');

> > (Number)   77.1234

Answer (score 1):

You can try this search/replace:

```
pattern: /([0-9]e[-+][0-9])|[^-+0-9.]/gi
replacement: $1
```

example:

```
var result = yourNbr.replace(/(\de[-+]\d)|[^-+0-9.]/gi, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dirty_text = '*(@#123.45jkd';
var clean_text = dirty_text.replace(/(?![+-]?\d*\.?\d+|e[+-]\d+)[^0-9]/g,'');
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/WBVna/2/) with each of your examples.

Note that any string-cleaning routine like this is likely to run into lots of problems, unless it is run after every key press.  For example, it's one thing to clean up `x123.45e+5` into `123.45e+5`.  It's another thing entirely to try to clean it up if the user enters `123.45e+5678.9e+10`.  At some point, with more than one or two stray characters, like in `$1,234.56`, it's hard to tell what you even *want* to get back.